# How to split long struct tags in golang?

Tags: string, go, struct

Let's say I have following struct where `valid` is for validation of struct with custom messages for each validator (specially [govalidator](https://github.com/asaskevich/govalidator)).

```
type Login struct {
  Email    string `json:"email" valid:"required~Email is required,email~The email address provided is not valid"`
  Password string `json:"password" valid:"required~Password is required,stringlength(6|40)~Password length must be between 6 and 40"`
}
```

After adding a few validator, line is too long and not maintainable.

I want to split into new lines but [not supported by go](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/15893) and not compatible with [reflect.StructTag.Get](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructTag.Get).

However, according to my testing, validator works with multiline struct tags but vet fails.

Short, what is the correct way to split long struct tags ?

Answer (score 11):

As you noted, the *convention* expected by `StructTag.Get()` does not allow using newline characters in struct tags (if you do not follow the convention, `StructTag.Get()` will not work properly). In my opinion that is just too much stuff being squeezed into a single tag value.

If you want to store that much meta info about your structures, I would store it outside of struct tags, properly modeled by other structs, so they can be accessed / processed in a type-safe manner.

If you have no choice and you do need to put that much info into a single tag, then you have to choose between the convenience of using the ready `StructTag.Get()` method, or omit the convention, use whatever format you want to in the struct tags, and simply implement your own tag-parsing logic.